# Laravel post request with error "TokenMismatchException"

Tags: php, validation, laravel, controller, token

I'm getting this TokenMismatchException with Laravel 4.2. 
TokenMismatchException will show up when I trying to post request.
For example Login Page. 
If I submit that form TokenMismatchException will show up. 
Is there any way I can validate all post request submitted ?
Here's the error :

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

Here's my code :
**route.php**

```
Route::get('login',array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogin'))->before('guest');
Route::post('login',array('uses' => 'AuthController@postLogin'))->before('csrf');
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
   Route::get('dashboard', array('as' => 'panel', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@view_dashboard'));
});
```

**AuthController.php**

```
class AuthController extends Controller {
public function getLogin(){
    return View::make('users.login');
}

public function postLogin(){
    $rules = array('username' => 'required', 'password' => 'required');
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::route('login')->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $auth = Auth::attempt(array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    ), false);
    if(!$auth){
        return Redirect::route('login')->withErrors(array(
        'Maaf anda bukan sebagai admin..'
        ));
    }
    //return "Success";
    return Redirect::to('dashboard');
}   
}
```

**DashboardController.php**

```
class DashboardController extends Controller {

    public function view_dashboard(){
        return View::make('dashboard.view_home_admin');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you don't have hidden csrf field in your form.
try to add this in your form

`{{ Form::token() }}`

Comment: still not working..
i add {{Form::token()}} in my form.
{{ Form::open(array('autocomplete' => 'off')) }}
{{ Form::token() }}
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control top" autofocus>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control bottom">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Log in">
{{ Form::close() }}

Comment: what is the action and the method of your form?